# Prevent sending duplicate email message in Case using Email related list

Tags: case, related-list, email2case, salesforce-classic, emailmessage

Is there a way to prevent the Users from sending a duplicate email from Case Email related list? I already checked a Salesforce article regarding this.

[image: Duplicate email sent]

I want to make the Send button to be disabled once the User already clicked it once. But standard related list is not customizable. I know that lightning experience has already this function but the users are only using classic as of now.

[image]

I want to know if there is another way from preventing the User of double sending an outbound email message like this.

[image: The highlighted emails are the same]

Thanks in advance!!